# Exercises for explaning homothety, homothetic center, similarity on line and plane, free vector and vector space

Tags: undergraduate-education, algebra, geometry, linear-algebra, exercises

I need the collection of exercises for such topics as:

- maps and transformations, composition of maps
- homothety, rotation homothety, homothetic center
- similarities of the line and the plane
- free vector and vector space
- matrix arithmetic

for the beginning of the course of linear algebra.

Can you recommend anything out of your experience as a good source?